# Invert CSS3 Transform Matrix

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix

How, if I have a CSS3 Transform Matrix, can I invert this matrix?

E.g. if I had this matrix for rotating 45 degrees and translating 10px, 10px

matrix(0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476, -0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, -0.0000000000000008881784197001252, 14.142135623730951)

how can I calculate the inverse

matrix(0.7071067811865475, -0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, -14.142135623730951, 0.0000000000000008881784197001252)

for rotating -45 degrees and translate -10px, -10px? Is it always simply swapping the second and third argument and swapping the fifth and sixth element (while doing *-1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. In both cases (direct and inverse) dx & dy are applied after (or before... but always in the same order) rotation/scale.
One need to find an inverse matrix for the following one:

```
| a11 a12 dx |
| a21 a22 dy |
|  0   0  1  |
```

And discard the third row of the result.

In case, you only have the rotation and no scaling, inverse matrix would be something like

```
| a11 a21 a11*x+a21*y |
| a12 a22 a12*x+a22*y |
```

Comment: So how would I go about inverting that matrix? Which elements should be swapped with which? I don't know much about matrices and am looking for a quick fix if possible :-)

Comment: This could be googled easily. E.g. http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxinvr.htm http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: I had found these functions, but they appear quite complicated. I hoped there would be a simple swap (like I assumed) or some other easy function that I could apply. Do you know of any JS functions that inverse a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: So I found http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/api/matrix.html#inverse which seems to do the trick. I will try this out, and if it works, accept your answer.

Comment: It took some fiddling, but it works now! I can inverse CSS3 Matrix functions. Woo :-)